# Adding firewall rule with .reg file

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-registry, firewall, windows-firewall

I created a rule to block PotPlayer from connecting to specific ip addresses (it's servers).

It worked great so I made a .reg file to share it, but I had to test it to see if it worked.

I ran it and it got added to the firewall, but for some reason it just wasn't working at all. When I try to remove the rule I get:

[image: This dialog]

but then the rule actually disappears. When I try to edit the rule I get:

[image: This]

I think it worked at first but after I deleted it and changed a little bit and added again it just isn't anymore

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules]
"BlockPotIP.x86"="v2.27|Action=Block|Active=TRUE|Dir=Out|RA4=61.251.98.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=113.29.186.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=113.29.189.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=148.253.228.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=151.249.91.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=203.133.166.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=203.133.172.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=203.217.239.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=211.231.100.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=211.231.108.0/255.255.255.0|App=%ProgramFiles% (x86)\\DAUM\\PotPlayer\\PotPlayerMini.exe|Name=BlockPotIP.x86|"
"BlockPotIP.x64"="v2.27|Action=Block|Active=TRUE|Dir=Out|RA4=61.251.98.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=113.29.186.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=113.29.189.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=148.253.228.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=151.249.91.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=203.133.166.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=203.133.172.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=203.217.239.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=211.231.100.0/255.255.255.0|RA4=211.231.108.0/255.255.255.0|App=%ProgramFiles%\\DAUM\\PotPlayer\\PotPlayerMini.exe|Name=BlockPotIP.x64|"
```

Comment: In my case, reboot Windows (Server 2019) helps.